# Migrating data from one mysql database to another using talend

Tags: mysql, bigdata, etl, talend, talend-mdm

The goal is to migrate data from one mysql database to another, my concern is to define a text file that contains the parameters that defines the source database (host, port, databasename, etc.) and also the file parameters of the output database.

Actually, what I use is the following schema:

```
tContextLoad_1 -> tFileInputDelimited_1-> tMysqlInput_1 (db_source) -> tMap->
tMysqlInput_2 (db_destination)
```

depending on the problem that has occurred is:

1- The `tContextLoad_1` text file content change is not supported and the pointing is always on the first database "source database".

2- When I create a second `tContextLoad_2` can not be connected by a (but) or (trigger-On subject Ok) with `tFileOutputDelimited_1` that linked with `tMysqlInput_2` (db_destination), how to define a file that contains the definition parameters of a base output data (host, databasename, identifier, password, etc.) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a configuration file like following,

```
<connections>
  <connection>
    <host></host>
    <port></port>
    <database></database>
    <table></table> 
    <user></user>
    </password></password>
  </connection>

  <connection>
    <host></host>
    <port></port>
    <database></database>
    <table></table> 
    <user></user>
    </password></password>
  </connection>
</connections>
```

And then you can iterate on connection tag to fetch the DB details and then assign them to variables and use it.

So the flow would be like,
tFileInputXML-->SetGlobalVar-->tMySQLConnection-->tMySQLInput-->tMap-->tMySQLOutput

Answer (score 0):

You can either define a single file, but with different parameter names for the source connection and target connection, or define 2 files : one for the source and one for the target, in that case your parameters can have the same name :

1. Single context file with different parameter names:

`tFileInputDelimited_1 (context file) -- tContextLoad_1
        |
     OnSubjobOk
        |
Source(host1,db1,user1,pwd1) -- target(host2,db2,user2,pwd2)`

2. Different context files having the same parameter names:

`tFileInputDelimited_1 (1st context file) -- tContextLoad_1
        |
     OnSubjobOk
        |
Source(host,db,user,pwd) -- temp_file
        |
     OnSubjobOk
        |
tFileInputDelimited_2 (2nd context file) -- tContextLoad_2
        |
     OnSubjobOk
        |
temp_file -- target(host,db,user,pwd)`

I'm sure you'll agree with me that the 1st solution is simpler, and more efficient.

Your context files could be like this : key=value

```
host=myHost
db=myDB
user=myUser
```